# Is $f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\cos n x }{\sqrt{n}}$ monotonic on $(0,0.1)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, monotone-functions

Is the function $f$ defined by$$f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\cos n x }{\sqrt{n}}$$ monotonic on the interval $(0,0.1)$? By Dirichlet's test, the series converges on this interval.

Does it define a monotonically decreasing function?

I have tried to plot its graph. It seems that it is indeed monotonic. But as in numerics, I can only take a finite number of terms, the graph always displays some oscillation close to $x =0$ (the series is not uniformly converging on the interval), so I think decisive answer can come only from analytics.

This problem comes from my research.

I am curious whether some asymptotic analysis will be helpful.

Below is the graph of the function. I have taken 1000 terms.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include additional context.  Where does this problem come from?  Is it from a class?  If so, what class?  What tools to you have available to work with (e.g. theorems, definitions, etc)?  What motivates the question?  Why do you think that $f$ might be decreasing (or not)?

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: I will undelete my answer when context is added. You might include your plot to see if the function looks like $\sqrt{\frac\pi{2x}}$ near $x=0$.

Comment: @robjohn I think now all your requirements are satisfied. I would be interested in your answer.

Comment: Your plot is on $[0,7]$. From your post, I would have thought your plot was on $[0,0.1]$. It's very hard to see what the function looks like on the interval of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Riemann sum, $t=nx$ and $\mathrm{d}t=x$. As $x\to0$,
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(nx)}{\sqrt{nx}}x\\
&\sim\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{t}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\sqrt{\frac\pi{2x}}
\end{align}
$$
Using Riemann-Stieltjes integration:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}\\
&=\int_{0^+}^\infty\frac{\cos(tx)}{\sqrt{t}}\,\mathrm{d}(t-\{t\})\\
&=\int_{0^+}^\infty\frac{\cos(tx)}{\sqrt{t}}\,\mathrm{d}t
-\int_{0^+}^\infty\frac{\cos(tx)}{\sqrt{t}}\,\mathrm{d}\{t\}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{t}}\,\mathrm{d}t
-\int_0^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{t}}\,\mathrm{d}\{t\}+O\!\left(x^2\right)\\
&=\sqrt{\frac\pi{2x}}+\zeta\!\left(\tfrac12\right)+O\!\left(x^2\right)
\end{align}
$$
If we continue in this fashion, we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{\frac\pi{2x}}+\zeta\!\left(\tfrac12\right)-\frac{\zeta\!\left(-\tfrac32\right)}2x^2+\frac{\zeta\!\left(-\tfrac72\right)}{24}x^4+O\!\left(x^6\right)
$$

Comment: I'm not sure how this is related to monotonicity. It's not an alternating sum (the zeta factors have different signs), we can't use it to bound $f(x) - \sqrt {\pi/(2 x)}$.

Comment: For small $x$, the only terms that are significant are the first two. However, $\zeta(-3/2)\approx-0.0254852$, $\zeta(-7/2)\approx0.0044410$, $\zeta(-11/2)\approx-0.0026715$, $\zeta(-15/2)\approx0.0032690$, so the signs of the coefficients alternate and so do the signs of the zeta function (the zeta function is $0$ at the negative even integers and alternates from one interval to the next). Thus, all the terms following $\zeta(1/2)$ are positive. However, the function is decreasing over this interval.

Comment: But where does the monotonicity follow from? (What I meant is that with an alternating sum, we could establish bounds on the derivative and prove that it's negative.)

Comment: You can compute the derivative: $-\sqrt{\frac\pi{8x^3}}-\zeta\!\left(-\frac32\right)x+\zeta\!\left(-\frac72\right)\frac{x^3}6$ and note that it is negative. If you want, a remainder term can be computed.

Comment: There is a small interval where it's negative. Without estimating the remainder (which is not trivial to do), this doesn't prove it's negative on $(0, 1/10)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the integral representation of the polylogarithm,
$$f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac {\cos n x} {\sqrt n} =
\frac 1 2 \operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(e^{i x}) +
 \frac 1 2 \operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(e^{-i x}) =
\int_1^\infty \frac {t \cos x - 1}
 {t \sqrt {\pi \ln t \,} (1 - 2 t \cos x + t^2)} dt, \\
f(x_2) - f(x_1) =
(\cos x_2 - \cos x_1) \int_1^\infty \frac {t^2 - 1}
 {\sqrt {\pi \ln t \,} (1 - 2 t \cos x_1 + t^2) (1 - 2 t \cos x_2 + t^2)} dt.$$
The last integrand is positive on $(1, \infty)$, therefore $f$ is monotonously decreasing on $(0, \pi)$.

Comment: This is more direct!

Comment: But I am confused. If the function is monotonic, then it is differentiable almost everywhere. However, by term-by-term differentiation, I would expect that the function is not differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: @S.Kohn Therefore the sum cannot be differentiated term-by-term. Differentiating the polylogarithm gives $f'(x)$ explicitly.

Comment: I am shocked. This even means $f$ can be differentiated many many times!

Comment: @S.Kohn It's even real analytic on $(0, 2 \pi)$.