# Is the function $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(nx)/\sqrt{n}$ differentiable on $(0,\pi)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

By term-by-term differentiation, I would expect this function is not differentiable almost everywhere. However, it is claimed that this function is monotonic, which would imply that it is differentiable almost everywhere. See the thread below:

[Is $f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\cos n x }{\sqrt{n}}$ monotonic on $(0,0.1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162611/is-fx-sum-n-geq-1-frac-cos-n-x-sqrtn-monotonic-on-0-0-1)

So, which one is true?

Comment: You have already been informed in the comments to the post you have cited that differentiability does not imply that you can differentiate term by term. This function is differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{inx} n^{-1/2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sum_{m=1}^n e^{imx}) (n^{-1/2}-(n+1)^{-1/2}) $ $=\frac{e^{ix}}{1-e^{ix}}+\frac{e^{ix}}{1-e^{ix}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{inx}(n^{-1/2}-(n+1)^{-1/2})$ whose differentiability is obvious since $n^{-1/2}-(n+1)^{-1/2}=\frac12 n^{-3/2}+O(n^{-5/2})$

Comment: @reuns  ingenious!